# Is there a name for the shape or volume of a wankel motor 'valve'?

Tags: geometry

Is there a name for the shape or volume of a 'valve' of a wankel motor other than 'slightly bulged equilateral triangle'?

Comment: Wikipedia's [Wankel engine entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wankel_engine) notes that the engine's chamber is an [epitrochoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epitrochoid) and the rotor is a [Reuleaux triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle).

Comment: Thanks! I haven't noticed.